# How to make checkboxs required in a Spring WebFlow Project with Dojo

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, dojo, spring-webflow

How to make checkboxs required in a Spring WebFlow Project with Dojo.  I would like to know how to make the checkbox required on submit of the following page.  I don't want the submit to work if the user did not click one of the check box options.  thanks.

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/fmt"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>



<style type="text/css" media="screen">
 @import url("<c:url value="/resources/dojo/resources/dojo.css"/>");
 @import url("<c:url value="/resources/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css"/>");
</style>     

<script djconfig="parseOnLoad: true"
 src="<c:url value="/resources/dojo/dojo.js"/>" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"
 src="<c:url value="/resources/spring/Spring.js" />"> </script>
<script type="text/javascript"
 src="<c:url value="/resources/spring/Spring-Dojo.js" />"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">dojo.require("dojo.parser");</script>

<html>
<head>
<title>Spring 3.0 MVC - Web Flow Example</title>
</head>
<body class="claro">
    <h2>CheckBox Test</h2>
    <p>
    <p>
    <form:form commandName="customer" id="customer">
        <input type="hidden" name="_flowExecutionKey"
            value="${flowExecutionKey}" />
        <div id="container">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td><font color=red><form:errors path="sex" /></font><b>Do you have a kid(s) of the follow sex type:</b></td>
                    <td><form:checkbox path="sex" id="sex" value="MALE" /> MALE |  
                        <form:checkbox path="sex" id="sex" value="FEMALE" />FEMALE
                        <script type="text/javascript">
                            dojo.query("#sex input[type='checkbox']").forEach(function(element){
                                Spring.addDecoration(new Spring.ElementDecoration({
                                    elementId: element.id,
                                    widgetType : "dijit.form.CheckBox",
                                    widgetAttrs : { checked : element.checked, required : true,
                                        validate: function (){
                                               if(dojo.query("INPUT[type='checkbox']", 'customer').filter(function(n){return n.checked;}).length > 0){return true;} else {alert('choose a type');return false;}
                                          }
}
                                }));
                            });
                        </script>
                        </td></tr>
                        </table>
        </div>
        <p>
        <input type="submit" name="_eventId_submit" id="submit" value="Submit" />
        <input type="submit" name="_eventId_cancel" value="Cancel" />
        <p>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            Spring.addDecoration(new Spring.ValidateAllDecoration({
                elementId : 'submit',
                event : 'onclick'
            }));
        </script>
    </form:form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you can use the validate function in your decoration

Comment: i been trying that. I cant get it to work. can you post a sample!

Comment: isnt it better to use radio button instead of checkbox ??
If you want the checkbox to be required..

Comment: no we need checkbox it. the user has to say yes to two questions before the form can be submitted. dont look at the questions. its really to diffent questions in real life

Answer (score 0, accepted):

let me guess: 0 or only 1 of your checkboxes really has the decoration on it.

couple of things here: checkboxes are not radiobuttons and you shouldn't be using them as such.

you want different ids and paths for every checkox because every checkbox has a different field.

even if you managed to do what you want, somebody could check both male and female...

you can use multiple checkboxes with form:checkbox but they would be linked to an array or a list

example of validate function (if it's the only checkboxes you have, otherwise query on a class or something like that):

```
validate: function (){
           if(dojo.query("INPUT[type='checkbox']", 'customer').filter(function(n){return n.checked;}).length > 0){return true;} else {alert('choose a type');return false;}
      }
```

Comment: no we need checkbox it. the user has to say yes to two questions before the form can be submitted. its really two diffent questins in real life

Comment: in that case just put different ids and put decoration with validate function for each of them. same validate function as radiobutton